# Determine type of receiver automatically from the port

Tags: java, port, serial-communication

I am developing an application that communicates with a GPS receiver through the communication port.

Each receiver type has its own set of native commands to operate it and currently i choose the type of the receiver (Ublox, Omnistar, Novatel etc.) manually.

I was wondering whether there is some option to make the determination process automatic? 
Is there any way of determining the receiver type only by connection to the port?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have zero experience with serial communication with GPS receivers, but maybe a general insight could help until a suitable expert comes along.

The way I see it, you have two options - either ask the received for its make/model/protocol type if such a query exists for these types of devices, or if they can be somehow made to provide some identifying information.

Or you can do some intelligent guesswork... If each device has a command that's unique to it, preferably one with a deterministic response, you can try sending each of these commands to the device. Then just look up the response in a pre-defined table and see which device matches. If you know that command `A` produces result `X` in device `1` (and only in that device), then by sending `A` and getting `X`, you can tell that device `1` is connected. Just make sure not to send anything dangerous - don't randomly send command `A` if for device `2` it means "delete everything and power off".

Comment: Thanx. I was thinking about the same thing. Create some predefined messages that each work on a specific type of receiver. Sending them one by one until receiving proper reply. Maybe someone here would have a different approach.